# Find specifc text in multiple columns in excel

Tags: excel, vba, search, substring, vlookup

I've got a formula that's been puzzling me for a while - I feel I'm close but the solution is evading me so I'm turning to you wizards. This questions is similar to [Excel VLOOKUP and SEARCH combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811521/excel-vlookup-and-search-combination).

Problem:

I want to look up a value which is a pair of codes separated by a dash, ex.
`01-05`
`A1-B2`
`AB-90`
, within columns A and B and return a result from C.

The issue is that I'm searching in two columns, which may include multiple codes separated by commas:

```
Col A          Col B           Col C

01             05, B2          Result1
A1             B2              Result2
AB, AC         90, 91, 92      Result3
```

I was thinking that a `=if(isnumber(search(` function would be the key but I can't figure how to have it check the entire column and once found, check the column next to it for the 2nd part of the code.

Ideally, the formula would perform as such, where in the above example, if I were to run this formula on the criteria `01-05` it would return `Result1`.

Appreciated!

Comment: did you come up to anything with answers given up to date?

Comment: currently testing OldUgly's fix, seems to be really close and just working out the kinks

Comment: Both answers below were close - user's below provided the most results, but still errored on some that there should be answers for

Answer (score 1):

If you put the code you are looking for in Column D, then your formula in Column E, the following formula will accomplish what you are looking for ...

`=IF(OR(ISERROR(FIND(LEFT(D2,2),A2)),ISERROR(FIND(RIGHT(D2,2),B2)),LEN(D2)=0),"",C2)`

And then fill it down.

The formula searches for the left two characters from the code in Column A. If it's not found, an error is thrown. It also looks for the right two characters from the code in Column B. If it's not found, an error is thrown. If the code you are looking for is blank, no error is thrown, so we need to check that case.

So if there is an error searching for the left part, or an error searching for the right part, or there is no code to look for, return a blank. Otherwise, return the result.

Below are some examples ...

[image]

---

**Updated based on comments**

On Sheet1, the data looks like this ...

[image]

... On Sheet2, we have results like this ...

[image]

Where Cell `B2` contains this formula (filled down)

```
{=CONCAT(IF(ISERROR(FIND(LEFT(A2,2),Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3)),"",IF(ISERROR(FIND(RIGHT(A2,2),Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3)),"",IF(LEN(A2)<1,"",Sheet1!$C$1:$C$3))))}
```

---

**Updated due to version-itis**

When all else fails, go to VBA. Attached is an example Function. It gets the same results as shown above. It is invoked with formula in Column B, filled down ...

```
=FindResult(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3,Sheet1!$C$1:$C$3)
```

Code ...

```
Function FindResult(inString As String, LeftRange As Range, RightRange As Range, ReturnRange As Range) As String
Dim strArr() As String
Dim myCellLeft As Range, myCellRight

'initial
FindResult = ""
If LeftRange Is Nothing Then GoTo Done:
If RightRange Is Nothing Then GoTo Done:
If ReturnRange Is Nothing Then GoTo Done:

' get the two halfs
strArr = Split(inString, "-")
If UBound(strArr) < 1 Then GoTo Done:

' Search the left range for the left half, the right range for the right half
For Each myCellLeft In LeftRange
    If InStr(1, myCellLeft.Value, strArr(0)) > 0 Then
        For Each myCellRight In RightRange.Rows(myCellLeft.Row)
            If InStr(1, myCellRight.Value, strArr(1)) > 0 Then
                FindResult = ReturnRange.Rows(myCellLeft.Row)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next myCellRight
        If FindResult <> "" Then Exit For
    End If
Next myCellLeft
' clean up
Done:
Erase strArr
Set myCellLeft = Nothing
Set myCellRight = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: So this is great, however, it looks like it can only search in A2/B2 for the criteria in D2. My situation is I have columns A, B, C on one sheet, and Column D and E on another, where I'm trying to pull the corresponding result for each code, if it exists.


My formula I have currently performs similarly to what you have, however I'm looking to have it search all of column A/B, so I could hypothetically, going off your above sample, have AC-92 in D2 and it would still pull Result3

Comment: It's simple enough to move Columns D and E to a different tab. In order to search the entire set, you will need to use array formulae. I'm away from my computer now, but can look into later.

Comment: @IanSchneider - is this closer to what you were looking for?

Comment: It looks like it worked in your example above, which is pretty much identical to what I need, however it's erroring out in the first argument for me, the if(iserror(find(right(. I'm also not understanding the need for concatenate? looks like it only has half the function in there anyway

Comment: It's a CSE formula, so it generates an array. Without the CONCAT, it returns the first array element, which is often "". CONCAT puts all of the answers together - typically `Result1&""&""` or `""&Result2&""` or `""&""&Result3`. And CONCAT should enclose everything - so maybe there's a problem with the brackets.

Comment: ah that makes sense why it's not working, looks like it's only in excel16? I'm running on 2010, so to make this function I would replace with concatenate at the beginning, and it then doesn't need the rest of the argument?

Comment: Sorry - I see just now it was introduced in 2016. It works a little different than CONCATENATE with arrays. So it may not work.

Comment: yup it was the brackets! I moved the concatenate brackets to after the first and second "" and it's pulling results now. It's pulling the first result however which isn't correct, I'm looking into why so. Noticed in my example it was based on comma separation in cols A and B, but I actually have semi-colons

Comment: The equation is lengthy because `AND()` and `OR()` don't work as you would want with arrays - so you need to use nested `IF()` statements.

Comment: hey well I appreciate it! Noted that this is an appropriate answer for Excel 2016

Answer (score 1):

the "formula" approach is, to my knowledge, quite verbose and cumbersome as follows:

```
=IF(
        ISNA(
                   IFERROR(MATCH(LEFT(D1,SEARCH("-",D1)-1),Codes!$A$1:$A$100,0),
                                     IFERROR(MATCH("*"&LEFT(D1,SEARCH("-",D1)-1)&",*",Codes!$A$1:$A$100,0),
                                                       MATCH("*,"&LEFT(D1,SEARCH("-",D1)-1)&"*",Codes!$A$1:$A$100,0)))
                   *
                   IFERROR(MATCH(RIGHT(D1,LEN(D1)-SEARCH("-",D1)),Codes!$B$1:$B$100,0),
                                      IFERROR(MATCH("*"&RIGHT(D1,LEN(D1)-SEARCH("-",D1))&",*",Codes!$B$1:$B$100,0),
                                                        MATCH("*,"&RIGHT(D1,LEN(D1)-SEARCH("-",D1))&"*",Codes!$B$1:$B$100,0)))
                   ),

         "Not Found",

          IF(IFERROR(MATCH(LEFT(D1,SEARCH("-",D1)-1),Codes!$A$1:$A$100,0),
                                   IFERROR(MATCH("*"&LEFT(D1,SEARCH("-",D1)-1)&",*",Codes!$A$1:$A$100,0),
                                                      MATCH("*,"&LEFT(D1,SEARCH("-",D1)-1)&"*",Codes!$A$1:$A$100,0)))
                <>
                IFERROR(MATCH(RIGHT(D1,LEN(D1)-SEARCH("-",D1)),Codes!$B$1:$B$100,0),
                                    IFERROR(MATCH("*"&RIGHT(D1,LEN(D1)-SEARCH("-",D1))&",*",Codes!$B$1:$B$100,0),
                                                      MATCH("*,"&RIGHT(D1,LEN(D1)-SEARCH("-",D1))&"*",Codes!$B$1:$B$100,0))), 

               "Different rows",

                INDEX(Codes!C:C,IFERROR(MATCH(RIGHT(D1,LEN(D1)-SEARCH("-",D1)),Codes!$B$1:$B$100,0),
                                                       IFERROR(MATCH("*"&RIGHT(D1,LEN(D1)-SEARCH("-",D1))&",*",Codes!$B$1:$B$100,0),
                                                                         MATCH("*,"&RIGHT(D1,LEN(D1)-SEARCH("-",D1))&"*",Codes!$B$1:$B$100,0))))
               )
        )
```

where I used a (hopefully) more readable format and assumed:

- "Codes" as the sheet name whose columns "A" ("first" code), "B" ("second" code) and "C" ("Results") are placed
- codes pairs are to be placed in column "D" of any sheet
- formula is to be placed in column "E" adjacent to above mentioned column "D" cells

you may want to consider a "VBA" approach like the following

```
Sub main()
Dim codesSht As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range, found As Range, codesRng As Range
Dim index1 As Long

Set codesSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Codes") '<== change "codes" sheet reference as per your needs
Set codesRng = codesSht.Range("A:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results") '<== change "Results" sheet reference as per your needs
    For Each cell In .Range("D1:D" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        Set found = codesRng.Resize(, 1).Find(What:=Split(cell.Value, "-")(0), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            index1 = found.Row
            Set found = codesRng.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 1).Find(What:=Split(cell.Value, "-")(1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
            If Not found Is Nothing Then If found.Row = index1 Then cell.Offset(, 1).Value = codesRng(index1, 3)
        End If
    Next cell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: hey thanks! while this was pretty wordy, it worked for a decent amount. Came up with some errors on answers I would of expected but not bad. I don't believe VBA is appropriate for what I'm trying to do but I will test it later.

Comment: Seems to be pulling in "Different Rows" for a lot that should have results, I'm going to test the VBA as well as tinker with the huge formula and see which turns out better

Comment: VBA did not work - however, I removed the section of your code for the different rows result, and now it's pulling the first result pertaining to the left 2 characters of the code in D - ex. is there is `D3-16` with `result1` and `D3-02` with `result2`, both lines will pull `result1`. I think the answer lies in the last section with the index(match(.

Comment: If you post data for which you encounterrd errors for both formula and VBA approache, I 'll have a look